# Select query 0=0 Vs not exists

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table contains 100 million rows and I found the below query (A), which is taking time. I am thinking to change it to (B), is it the same?

Is this query (A) :

```
SELECT * 
FROM   tab1 
WHERE  code = 1 
       AND TYPE = 'A' 
       AND 0 = (SELECT Count(1) 
                FROM   tab1 
                WHERE  code = 1 
                       AND tr_type = 'APPROVE' 
                       AND security = 'Y')
```

Similar to this (B) ?

```
SELECT * 
FROM   tab1 
WHERE  code = 1 
       AND TYPE = 'A' 
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                       FROM   tab1 
                       WHERE  code = 1 
                              AND tr_type = 'APPROVE' 
                              AND security = 'Y' 
                              AND ROWNUM = 1)
```

Comment: @HoneyBadger  Yes I mean not exists

Comment: @RaymondNijland I am working with oracle , beside query B has correct indexing and selecting 1 rows (in MySQL its limit 1 or top 1). would this also cause performance issue ( even for msql rdbms  ) ?

Comment: Never mind iám normally 95% of the time under the MySQL tag on stackoverflow i geuss i wasn't fully awake right there .. I believe Oracle has a better optimizer with co-related subqueries vs MySQL

Comment: Not that it makes any difference, but the standard SQL expression for counting rows is `count(*)` not `count(some_arbitrary_literal)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes same query.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM tab1 
 WHERE code = 1 
   AND type = 'A' 
   AND 0 = (SELECT Count(1) 
              FROM tab1 
             WHERE code = 1 
              AND  tr_type = 'APPROVE' 
              AND  security = 'Y')
```

If we will take output of inner query in the above query

```
SELECT Count(1) 
  FROM tab1 
 WHERE code = 1 
   AND tr_type = 'APPROVE' 
   AND security = 'Y'
```

I am assuming , Record with `code = 1` , `TR_TYPE = 'APPROVE'` and `security = 'Y'` is present. So output will be 1. (Assumption is only one matching record is present).

```
SELECT * 
  FROM tab1 
 WHERE code =1 
   AND type='A' 
   AND 0=1 (replacing the result)
```

So this will not return any data as 0 is never equal to 1.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM tab1 
 WHERE code = 1 
   AND type = 'A' 
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                     FROM tab1 
                    WHERE code = 1 
                      AND tr_type = 'APPROVE' 
                      AND security = 'Y' 
                      AND rownum = 1)
```

Now checking the above query, inner query return 1 as the data with the where clause is present so result will be

```
SELECT * 
  FROM tab1 
 WHERE code =1 
   AND type='A' 
   AND NOT EXISTS (1)
```

`Exists(If any record found) = true` and in our case `Exists(1) = true` so 
`Not Exist (1) = false`. Which denotes to false as it has 1 record , so it will also not return the data.

So if you are asking that both query will return same output. So It will return same output.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend writing the query as:

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM tab1 t1
WHERE t1.code = 1 AND
      t1.TYPE = 'A' AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM tab1 tt1
                  WHERE tt1.code = t1.code AND 
                        tt1.tr_type = 'APPROVE' 
                        tt1.security = 'Y'
                 );
```

The changes are:

- Table aliases are introduced.
- All columns are qualified.
- The `rownum = 1` condition is removed.

The latter is between redundant and dangerous.  `EXISTS`/`NOT EXISTS` is already looking for any row that matches.  Including `rownum` *could* affect the optimizer.

Your first version has to find *all* matches in order to calculate the count.  That can be much more expensive that determining that there are no matches or finding the first one.

For performance, you want indexes on `tab1(code, tr_type, security)` and `tab1(code, type)`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the output will be same because its just the interchangeable way to use it however in terms of time complexity the second one is optimised.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are the same, however i would explicitly put an alias on the table being used in the non exists and alias the columns being compared to.Eg:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM tab1 
 WHERE code = 1 
   AND type = 'A' 
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                     FROM tab1 b
                    WHERE b.code = 1 
                      AND b.tr_type = 'APPROVE' 
                      AND b.security = 'Y' 
                      AND rownum = 1)
```